# i have a json url having video_url and with reclyer viewer when click item play video from video_url

Tags: android, json, video, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

Here is my `JSON`,

```
[{
    "id": "3",
    "title": "Example",
    "image": "https:\/\/media.novinky.cz\/993\/329935-top_foto2-s92qn.jpg",
    "video_url": "http:\/\/www.sample-videos.com\/video\/mp4\/720\/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4",
    "data": "02\/02\/2016"
}]
```

Here is my Adapter Event When click on Image and go to play video with video_url but I don't know how.

```
 holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,Video_player.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            intent.putExtra("video_url",my_data.toString());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
 }
```

Here is my player activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    String Url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("video_url");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player); 
    emVideoView = (EMVideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_plyer); 
    Bundle bundle =getIntent().getExtras(); 
    emVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(Url));
}
```

How can I get video_url in go my video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(video url here);?

Comment: You are already passing `video_url` as Extra to the Intent. What is your issue?

Comment: @KNeerajLal but bro i don't know how to receive it in my player activity and don't know what i intent is incorrect or correct

Comment: What does `Log.e("video_url", my_data.toString());` before `context.startActivity(intent);` say?

Comment: @KNeerajLal  E/video_url: [com.ironheartdev.msjtvproject.MyData@4349b9, com.ironheartdev.msjtvproject.MyData@b32f1fe, com.ironheartdev.msjtvproject.MyData@2e09d5f, com.ironheartdev.msjtvproject.MyData@1023ac, com.ironheartdev.msjtvproject.MyData@4c5c875


i'm using ExoMedia for playvideo

Comment: This code is inside a `RecyclerView` `onBindView` method right? Also `my_data` is an `ArrayList` right? If yes change the `Log` to `Log.e("video_url", my_data.get(position).getVideoUrl());` and post the output here.

Comment: E/video_url: http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4
 E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Internal track renderer error.
                                                                                      com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

problem from receive activity

Comment: So the video link is good.

Comment: Here is my Video player  activity 


`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String Url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("video_url");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);
        emVideoView = (EMVideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_plyer);
        Bundle bundle =getIntent().getExtras();
        emVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(Url));`

Comment: Code looks good. Please add it to your question.

Comment: Have you tried a different URL? That site looks very laggy.

Comment: it working now thank you brother 
may i have your facebook ?

Comment: What did you change in the code? I don't use fb much. Same name on fb though. :)

Comment: i don't know which one :)